# Is there a way to print out the line number of a js file in the console log

Tags: console, google-chrome-devtools

For debugging purposes, I usually use something like `console.log('line number #')`.

Not sure if it's the best way to handle it but I think it would be helpful if I can just print out the line number of the line where I'm putting the `console.log()` **dynamically**.

Let's say:

```
1    //do something
2    if(file){
3        console.log('Line 3');
4        $('#uploads').css({ 'height' : 'auto' });
5    } else { 
6       console.log(getLineNumber());   //just an example
7       $('#tags').val(temp);
8    }
```

In the above, if I happen to remove line 1 for instance, line 3 will be technically incorrect as the line number is decremented by 1 but the log will still show 3. But in line 6, suppose `getLineNumber()` returns the line number, then it will still make sense even after a line above has been removed.

So is there an easy way which acts like `getLineNumber()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `onerror` event handler for that.

See the last example on this page: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/javascript_error_handling.htm

Direct link to example: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cgi-bin/practice.cgi?file=javascript_40

Comment: But there will be cases which are not exactly errors. Maybe I would just want to check if the script execution went through inside an `if, else` condition or a loop.

Comment: There is no clean solution but workarounds like this one `new Error().lineNumber` -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2343343/how-can-i-determine-the-current-line-number-in-javascript