# Chrome on Android resizes font

Tags: android, html, css, google-chrome, font-size

Apparently once paragraph of text reaches a certain length, Google Chrome on Android decides to resize the text and make it larger (causing all kinds of fun). Now I have a website where about half of the `p`-tags follow the size I've set and the other half change as they please - apparently depending on the length of the paragraph.

How on earth do I fix this?

Comment: Do you have an example? Also, which Android and Chrome version?

Answer (score 102):

Add `max-height: 999999px;` to the element you want to prevent font boosting on, or its parent.

Comment: Android Chrome only applies font boosting to elements with dynamic height. As soon as you specify a height or max-height, font boosting is not applied. Setting max-height to a large number is simple and should have no side effects.

Comment: Just a warning for this. This solved the problem I had with Chrome fonts on android not playing nice. **However** it broke the ipad view of the site on specific versions of ios.

Comment: As well as it caused some issues on ipad for css3 transitions.

Comment: Using this significantly breaks the layout of many elements in Safari (5.1.7), even if you are not utilizing max-height or defined heights to begin with. A few sites were completely unusable, all of the structural `div` elements were collapsed awkwardly to the top of the page. Do not "blanket" your site with a max-height definition! Use only where needed, and test thoroughly.

Comment: @RadGH can you try using `{min-height:1px;}` instead?

Comment: @moeffju Using min-height in the same situation does not break safari. I can't test if it disabled font boosting anymore though. According to [Bug 84186 ](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=84186), the parent or grandparent (but not higher) "must have a max-height greater than the original element" in order to disable font boosting. I cannot confirm if this is actually the case.

Comment: Whelp... Just when I thought I'd seen it all... Another crazy glitch with another crazy fix. FWIW I'm not seeing any issues in Safari, and `min-height: 1px` unfortunately had no effect. `max-height: 999999px` does the trick though. My case was very long content transitioning during route entry/leave. Font boosting happened either during or just after the transition, not sure which, but it caused a very noticeable shift.

Comment: @moeffju this works indeed, where did you find this solution ? what is the source.

Answer (score 63):

Include the following `<meta>` tag in the document `<head>`:

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`

This will correctly establish the view frame, and thus eliminate the need for "FontBoosting".

Comment: This is definitely the preferred solution. If you care about how things look in mobile, then take ownership of your viewport!

Comment: This doesn't disable font boosting, though.

Comment: It certainly corrects unwanted scaling and I am going to use it in future.

Comment: As a note, I have `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=0.5, user-scalable=no">` and I'm still getting Chromes awful scaling

Comment: That's better because the font is legible.  It's maintaining proportion while increasing size for legibility.  Perfect for me.

Comment: This works but it has an issue, your website loads with full width and height instead of fit to browser window.  It mainly causes problem in vertical orientation.

Comment: Thanks - this seems to work well.  But I'm aghast that plain old-fashioned web 1.0 sites are rendered so poorly by modern mobile browsers, and considered "non-responsive" and "broken" by google.  http://isitvivid.com/blog/google-penalty-non-responsive-websites

Comment: In my case it alone did not work - the font was nicely readable in short paragraphs, but unexpectedly small in longer paragraphs. I had to add `text-size-adjust: none` to prevent Android Chrome from decreasing text size for the longer paragraphs.

Comment: @Sam: `user-scalable=no` is a great way to make people who don't have perfect vision leave your site, especially if nobody checks whether images are at all viewable on a small screen. FireFox on Android has an option for overriding this, for good reason.

Answer (score 28):

There is now a CSS property you can set to control this:

```
text-size-adjust: none;
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-size-adjust

Comment: text-size-adjust: none worked for me on lastest android chrome.

Comment: This is the preferred solution if you are using a gas deployed as web app.

Comment: Appears most mobile browsers support this code. Works fine!

Answer (score 16):

Put this in your reset. `html * {max-height:1000000px;}`

Comment: was causing issues with me for sticky footer, had to do html body * instead

Comment: This is a little too aggressive, *unless* you're actually experiencing an issue in many unpredictable elements. Otherwise it'd be better to target only the problem elements.

Comment: @Chase - in my case they were unpredictable (dynamic) elements, so we did have to use a `*` approach. That said, I'd argue this is one of those obscure things that you'd likely forget about and may cause problems in future, so for maintainability I'd probably have left it at `*` even if _at the time_ it was just one/a few elements.

Comment: Right after I found this thread and commented, I started seeing additional issues I suspected were related to font boosting. So, sure enough (at least for now) there's a `* max-height...` in my code LOL

Answer (score 6):

After some tests this rule helped me out. Must be added either to the element containing boosted text or it's parent depending on the div/table structure.

```
element or parent element { 
    /* prevent font boosting on mobile devices */
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    min-height: 1px;
    max-height: 999999px;
}
```

Maybe the width and heigth values must be corrected according your needs.

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution for my pages: give the parent element a width and height! The font will not go outside those borders, and so it will remain small(er).

Answer (score 1):

This is called "font boosting" and is described in some detail in this [WebKit bug](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=84186). There's currently no way to disable it.

Comment: Looks like it is indeed font boosting but it can be prevented by setting `max-height: 999999px` as @moeffju described.