# Cannot change font size of content article

Tags: css, joomla, joomla2.5

I use Joomla to build my website. I use Chrome to debug; when I show site with Phone Device of Chrome, all font-size of content Article auto increased.
I set font-size for all `p` elements, but but it doesn't work. I don't know the place to fix it and what happens with my site.

[image]

Comment: We need a link or code (more preferable).

Comment: Your problem might be font boosting. Setting max-height on the elements containing the boosted font might fix it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13430897/how-to-override-font-boosting-in-mobile-chrome

Comment: Red Devil: [link](http://goidaubangla.com/index.php/12-sevices/cham-soc-toc)