# jquery text size on load enlarged

Tags: jquery, accordion

I have add a jquery accordion to a web page create in Xara Web Designer (no choice). It all works well except when I view the accordion on an Android device, when I first load the page the content text in the open panel is larger than expected. If I close the panel and open the other they are all fine and if I go back to the original panel that too then become OK. It seems to be a problem that only affects Android devices on load. You can view a demo page using the link below;

[image]
See image on right

All advice is appreciated.

Comment: No difference for me. Looks very good: [**Preview**](http://snag.gy/kkWYw.jpg)

Comment: @PraveenKumar What device where you looking with and which version of Andriod?

Comment: Ohhhhhhhhhh!!! Sorry Chrome on Android 4.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that Android Font boosting was changing the size, I found the solution in this post

[how to override font boosting in mobile chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13430897/how-to-override-font-boosting-in-mobile-chrome)