# What does html * { max-height: 1000000px; } mean?

Tags: css

I've been inspecting one website I liked and I saw that they use `html * { max-height:10000000px; }` quite often. But what does it do?

EDIT: website url: http://yula-group.ru/

Comment: Perhaps you can post the website url for reference?

Comment: @james.brndwgn check the edit please

Comment: once paragraph of text reaches a certain length, chrome on android decides to resize the text and make it larger so adding `max-height: 999999px;` to the element they want to prevent font boosting on, or its parent.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like it has to do with font boosting for some browsers on mobile device. Related answers here: [Chrome on android resizes font](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11289166/chrome-on-android-resizes-font)
and here [how to override font boosting in mobile chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13430897/how-to-override-font-boosting-in-mobile-chrome)