# font-size bug when using viewport initial-scale < 1.0

Tags: android, html, css, google-chrome, viewport

I'm trying to make my html mobile page 1px equals 1 screen pixel.

So I use a initial-scale less than 1.0:

```
<meta id="viewport" name="viewport"
      content="width=device-width,initial-scale=0.33333333,maximum-scale=0.33333333,user-scalable=no" />
```

But in my chrome browser(both on pc emulation and android Chrome), some of the font-size was out of control, and absolutely randomly, I just cannot tell why.

Comment: You're probably experiencing "font boosting". Look at this question  and answers http://stackoverflow.com/q/11289166/5297207

Comment: Wow! It do! Thank you!