# font-size property on input element not Chrome and Safari in MacOS

Tags: css

There is an input field with a certain `font-size` property.

```
form input[type=search] {
  width: 60%;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  padding: .35em .4em;
}
```

By default, because of the font size property, the height of the input field changes as well. All the browsers in `Linux` and `Windows` honor the font-size property. `Firefox` in `MacOS` too.

However Safari and `Chrome/Opera` in `MacOS` don't. The input field size and font size doesn't change in Safari. `Chrome/Opera` increases the font size only when the input field is on focus.

[image: Input field out of focus in Chrome and out of focus in Safari]

[image: Input field on focus in Chrome (displayed correctly)]

[image: Input field on focus in Safari]

The expected display is that the font size is honored whether the field is on focus or off focus. Only Firefox in `MacOS` displays it correctly.

Comment: Do you use CSS resets? Apply them first. Also try to use class instead of `input[type=search]` or at least add quotes `input[type="search"]`

Comment: Yes, I do use css resets from meyerweb.com with slight modifications to certain properties like `body`.

Answer (score 0):

You want your font size specified in rem not em 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length#rem

It is always a good idea to specify line size (in em) and match it with height, if there is no clashing css this with most font-families will mean your text will be centered horizontally and the input field should be pretty much the same across browsers.

```
form input[type=search] {
   width: 60%;
   /* font-size: 1.1em; -- not em */
   font-size: 1.1rem; /* -- yes rem */
   padding: .35em .4em;
   line-height: 1.8em; /* -- add this -  whatever height you want in em */
   height: 1.8em; /* -- add this -  whatever height you want in em */
   box-sizing: border-box; /* -- you will probably want to add this because you are using padding */
}
```

box sizing link : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing

Comment: Also see the answer to this question, it may be contributing. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47783168/mobile-chrome-wrong-font-size-when-using-height-property?rq=1

Comment: I had used rem units as advised, but it doesn't resolve it. I have added the padding and line-height as well, but of no use. Only when I click on the field, the font size changes.

Comment: without seeing the actual code we can't trouble shoot it @the_beginner

Comment: The source code for the page is here at view-source:https://eduwatch.in/ and the css is https://eduwatch.in/assets/css/index.css. Note that only on Safari/Chrome/Opera on MacOS, I do get the inconsistency.