# How to store console.log() result as an object / variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, debugging, console

I would like to save the output of the console.log() function as an object, or as a variable.
I'm mainly interested in receiving object-results, as well as the line numbers.

The following is just to demonstrate, what i'm looking for:

```
var myobj = {"key":"value"}; // (<< in 'myjs.js, line 123)
var mylog = console.log( myobj );

// output mylog: {"key":"value"}, myjs.js:123
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: `console.log()` does not return any value... so it is not possible with console.log

Comment: infact `myObj` is `myLog`, Just assign it

Comment: Technically, you could overwrite the function in the console's prototype, but that seems like a terrible idea.

Comment: Do you want to save output as a String or an Object?

Comment: I would prefer as an object, but since i'm mainly interested in the line number, as a string would be a big help as well.

Answer (score 2):

you can use `new Error().lineNumber` to get line number
 For more info about determining line number - [determining line number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2343343/how-can-i-determine-the-current-line-number-in-javascript)

Comment: This is a very interesting hint, thank you!
Unfortunately, Error() does not seem to be as cross-browser compatible, as console().
If there should be a way to catch the console output, i'd prefer this.
So far, this one comes very close!

Answer (score 1):

You can overwrite console.log and call Error().stack in google chrome it show line numbers.

In google chrome stack look like this:

```
Error
    at Error (<anonymous>)
    at Console.console.log (http://localhost/test.js:6:27)
    at foo (http://localhost/test.js:13:13)
    at http://localhost/test.js:16:1
```

So the code need to fetch 3 line and remove `"at http://localhost"` and number of chars

```
(function(log) {
    console.log = function(o) {
        var stack = Error().stack.split('\n');
        log.call(console, JSON.stringify(o) + ', ' + stack[3].
            replace(/.*http:\/\/[^\/]*|:[0-9]+\)$/g, ''));
    };
})(console.log);


function foo() {
    console.log({foo: 'bar'});
}

foo();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try saving myObj object. That is what the logger will log.

Comment: I would like to receive the line number as well.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this from the link [Read the output of console.log](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/read-the-output-of-console-log)

```
function myFunctionThatMightHaveAnError(){
    // instead of just failing silently, actually throw an error
    $.error("My special error");
}
// Then use a try/catch block to handle it
try {
    myFunctionThatMightHaveAnError();
    alert("No error!"); // this line would only run if no error were thrown
} catch (e) {
    if(e == "My special error") {
        // Handle error
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I made a similar workaround myself, but i'm missing how to catch the line number.

Comment: this code is actually capturing the error output from the function so technically you are not reading console.log because you can't read the console.... as my knowledge so far,
as a result you can't capture the line number using this code ... or any