# How to get access to line number in file Copy filter task?

Tags: gradle

This is what I need:

I have log statements in my javascript files, they look like this:

log.d("some log message here")

I want to dynamically add fine name and line number to these during the copy task.
Ok, so adding the file name is probably easy enough, but how to I get access to line number? Strangely I could not find any information on how to do this.

The filter() method of Copy task just passing the actual line, it would be nice if it was passing 2 arguments - line and line number.

Here is the template of my task. I added comments of what I need to achieve.

I know I can get name of file from fileCopyDetails using fileCpyDetails.getSourceName() but I am stuck
on how to replace the lines that start with log.d() with a new log.d statement that has line number
I am really hoping someone can help me here.

```
task addLineNumbers(type: Copy) {
  into 'build/deploy'
  from 'source'
  eachFile { fileCopyDetails ->
    // Here I need to add line number to log.d("message")
    // to become log.d("[$fileName::$line] + $message")
    // for example, if original line in userdetails.js file was log.d("something logged here")
    // replace with log.d("[userdetails.js::43] something logged here")
  }

}
```

Comment: You might want to implement your own task for this, rather than using a `Copy` task. Implementing an Ant `FilterReader` would be another option.

Answer (score 1):

Not the most elegant solution, but works for me:

```
task addLineNumbers(type: Copy) {
    into 'build/deploy'
    from 'source'

    def currentFile = ""
    def lineNumber = 1

    eachFile { fileCopyDetails ->
        currentFile = fileCopyDetails.getSourceName()
        lineNumber = 1
    }

    filter { line ->
        if (line.contains('log.d("')) {
            line = line.replace('log.d("', "log.d(\"[${currentFile}::${lineNumber}]")
        }

        lineNumber++
        return line
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Copy task just copies files (it can filter/expand files using [Ant filters](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/filterchain.html) or Groovy [SimpleTemplateEngine](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/text/SimpleTemplateEngine.html)).  You're looking for a pre-processor of sorts.  I think it's possible to do that with a custom Ant filter, but it seems like a lot of work.

I think what people typically do is use something like this at runtime to find the file/line number: [How can I determine the current line number in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2343343/how-can-i-determine-the-current-line-number-in-javascript)

Comment: I am using a trick to determine file name and line number at runtime, but it's inefficient and it's exactly what I'm trying to fix with the build script so that I don't have to use this trick in production.