# Can I get the current line number in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I know this sounds like a strange thing to ask, but is there anyway to get the current line number in a TypeScript script so that it will be emitted to the resulting JavaScript code? I guess I'm looking for something like C's preprocessor

```
__LINE__
```

variable.

Edit: I'm asking about the current line in the TypeScript source file (which will usually be different from the corresponding line number in the resulting JavaScript file).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I determine the current line number in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2343343/how-can-i-determine-the-current-line-number-in-javascript)

Comment: Typescript transpiles into Javascript, hence this question is equivalent to asking the same for Javascript.

Comment: @IngoBürk nope, that's not necessarily the case.. Maybe he wants the current line in the typescript source code and not in the transpiled js code. What you can do, I guess, is use the solution of getting the js line number and then use the source map to get the line in the typescript source code.

Comment: @NitzanTomer True. Reading the question I can't tell which one it is, which means it's unclear what is being asked instead now. :-) I'll retract my vote if OP clarifies that this is what they want.

Comment: Sorry, I edited the question. I am indeed asking about the current line number in the TypeScript source file.

Comment: Well, as I wrote, you'll need to use the source map (the `.js.map` file the compiler outputs). It will help if you'll clarify on the scenario.

Comment: I know it is a bit late - but I had this same question and came up with a solution - I hope it helps you some - [Posted it over in my question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38194457/how-to-get-actual-line-within-source-for-custom-logging-in-typescript/38197778#38197778).

Comment: Same problem here. Any solution found in the end? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, I ended up parsing the .js.map files which worked fine.

Comment: Compile-time info like this would be a fantastic addition to TypeScript to put it further ahead of Javascript IMHO. It's a frustrating omission from Javascript.

Answer (score 3):

I think souremaps will do what you need. **Sourcemaps are a way to map a javascript file back to it's unmodified state**.

If you configure your typescript compiler to include sourcemaps then Chrome and other dev tools can reference your typescript files. The result would look like this:

```js
//index.ts

console.log('hey, here is a log!');

console.error('hey, here is an error');
```

Which would produce this in the console of Chrome's dev tools:

`hey, here is a log!       index.ts:3`

`hey, here is an error     index.ts:5`

The line numbers would be correct even though the typescript complier would strip out the empty lines and reformat the code.

Hope that helps!

Comment: What about in Node?