# How to get actual line # within source (for custom logging) in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, electron

Referencing [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1340872/how-to-get-javascript-caller-function-line-number-how-to-get-javascript-caller) I am using this bit of code to find the line number of the caller to my custom logging function:

```
/**
 * eLog - displays calling line number & message & dumps vars as pretty json string
 * @param {string} msg - string to display in log message
 * @param {any} dispVars - any number of variables (ellipsis , aka Rest parameters) to dump
 */
function eLog(msg:string,...dispVars:any[]){
    let caller_line = (new Error).stack.split("\n")[4];
    console.log(`eLog->Line#${caller_line}->${msg}->`);
    console.log(JSON.stringify((new Error).stack.split("\n"),null,2));
    dispVars.forEach(value => {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(value,null,2));
    });
}
```

Called like this:

```
eLog("eLog Test",this);
```

And while this does do a proper dump of the `.js` file line #, I need the Source line#, the `.ts` line number. How can I generate this properly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I went through this over the evening and came up with a function I am pleased with. Thanks for the help in getting started-

Separated it out into `log.ts`

```js
require('source-map-support').install({
 environment: 'node'
});


/**
 * eLog - displays calling line number & message & dumps vars as pretty json string
 * @param {string} msg - string to display in log message
 * @param {any} dispVars - any number of variables (ellipsis , aka Rest parameters) to dump
 * {@link https://github.com/evanw/node-source-map-support usable by typescript node-source-map-support module}
 * {@link https://github.com/mozilla/source-map/ Mozilla source-map library & project}
 * {@link http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/developertools/sourcemaps/ good introduction to sourcemaps}
 */
export function eLog(msg:string,...dispVars:any[]){
 /**
  * go one line back for the caller
  * @type {string}
  */
 let stackLine = (new Error).stack.split("\n")[2];
 /**
  * retrieve the file basename & positional data, after the last `/` to the `)` 
  */
 // 
 let caller_line = stackLine.slice(stackLine.lastIndexOf('/'),stackLine.lastIndexOf(')'))
 /**
  *  test for no `/` ; if there is no `/` then use filename without a prefixed path
  */ 
 if ( caller_line.length == 0 ) {
  caller_line = stackLine.slice(stackLine.lastIndexOf('('),stackLine.lastIndexOf(')'))
 }
 // 
 /**
  * filename_base - parse out the file basename; remove first `/` char and go to `:`
  */
 let filename_base = caller_line.slice(0+1,caller_line.indexOf(':'));
 /**
  * line_no - parse out the line number ; remove first `:` char and go to 2nd `:`
  */
 let line_no = caller_line.slice(caller_line.indexOf(':')+1,caller_line.lastIndexOf(':'));
 /**
  * line_pos - line positional - from the last `:` to the end of the string
  */
 let line_pos = caller_line.slice(caller_line.lastIndexOf(':')+1);
 console.log(`eLog called by ${filename_base} on line# ${line_no} @ char# ${line_pos} said:\n${msg}`);
 // print out the input variables as pretty JSON strings
 dispVars.forEach(value => {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(value,null,2));
 });
}
```

Which can be called with a simple:

```
eLog("eLog Test",this);
```

from any file so long as the function is loaded (such as)

```
import { eLog } from './log'
```

---

I hope that helps somebody else.

Cheers guys.
-Eric

Answer (score 0):

> How can I generate this properly

a.) The code you have is fairly dependent upon the user runtime (e.g. will not work in IE).

b.) You will need sourcemaps for js -> ts to work. Stuff that makes it easy doesn't exist already. The *defacto* raw package to use sourcemaps is : https://www.npmjs.com/package/source-map