# Unable to get line number In typescript

Tags: typescript, karma-jasmine, typeerror

I'm running a test but not able to determine the exact line where it fails
I put this code:

```
try {
   my code    
} catch (e) {
   console.log('LineNumber', e.lineNumber);
   console.log('Stack', e.stack);    
}
```

Here is what I get:

LOG: 'LineNumber', `undefined`

LOG: 'Stack', 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of null
at MyClass.method (./MyClass.ts?:8:27925)

What is `8:27925`?
How to get the exact line number in a test with typescript?

Answer (score 1):

> LOG: 'LineNumber', undefined

The `lineNumber` property is non-standard and only available in Firefox. I suspect you're seeing the `undefined` value because you're not using Firefox.
See [Error.prototype.lineNumber](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error/lineNumber) for more info.

> What is `8:27925`?

This is part of the stack trace. I believe it is `lineNumber:columnNumber`.

The `8` is the line number where the `Cannot read property 'push' of null at MyClass.method` error was thrown.

The `27925` is the column number. I assume it is so large because the TypeScript source has been compiled and possibly minified.

*Is the `lineNumber:columnNumber` convention documented anywhere? Please let me know in the comments if you know of something.*

> How to get the exact line number in a test with typescript?

See [How can I determine the current line number in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2343343/395461)