# Trace the line of code/file a function call originated from in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, debugging

I've written a very simple function to ensure ensure my applications do not break if I forget to remove a `console.log()`.

*Simply put:*

```
myNamespace.log = function( msg ){
   if( window.console ){
      console.log(obj);
   }
}
```

It works like a charm.  Alas, I very much liked the ability to see from which line of code and file my console messages came from.  **Is there a (chrome/FF friendly) way to get the file/line of code a function call?**

Comment: See [How to get JavaScript caller function line number? How to get JavaScript caller source URL?
](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1340872/how-to-get-javascript-caller-function-line-number-how-to-get-javascript-caller-s).  [scotts's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1340872/how-to-get-javascript-caller-function-line-number-how-to-get-javascript-caller-s/3444831#3444831) points to a cross-browser script that wraps all of the browser-specific methods.

Answer (score 2):

If it were my site, I'd use:

```
myNamespace.log = function( msg ){
  if( window.console && window.console.log && typeof window.console.log === "function" ){
    console.log(obj);
  }
}
```

I seriously doubt there's a browser-agnostic way to get source file line number.

Comment: well I just realized it's for my personal use so chrome/FF would suffice for this particular functionality.  What do the additional conditions in the if statement do?

Comment: Check to make sure that "window.console" actually has a "log" property, and that the property is really a function you can call. Probably overly paranoid, but if you want to really make sure that stray "console.log" calls definitely won't cause an exception that'd be more insurance.