# Showing console errors and alerts in a div inside the page

Tags: javascript, browser

I'm building a debugging tool for my web app and I need to show console errors in a div. I know I can use my own made console like object and use it, but for future use I need to send all console errors to window. Actually I want to catch console events.

Comment: Here's what I found helpful ultimately: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37081135/470749

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43725214/470749 down below is pretty cool.

Comment: https://github.com/bahmutov/console-log-div - is quite useful and comprehensive

Answer (score 79, accepted):

To keep the console working:

```
if (typeof console  != "undefined") 
    if (typeof console.log != 'undefined')
        console.olog = console.log;
    else
        console.olog = function() {};

console.log = function(message) {
    console.olog(message);
    $('#debugDiv').append('<p>' + message + '</p>');
};
console.error = console.debug = console.info =  console.log
```

Comment: Just thinking that check for `!= "undefined"` is only partially complete, later on we are assigning to `console.log ` anyway...

Comment: For those where this solution is not working: Have you considered, that this solution required jQuery becuase of this selector `$('#debugDiv')` ? Try using something like this instead: `document.getElementById('debugDiv').innerHTML += ('<p>' + message + '</p>');`

Comment: What about ReferenceErrors?

Answer (score 34):

Here's a way using closure, containing the old console log function in the scope of the new one.

```
console.log = (function (old_function, div_log) { 
    return function (text) {
        old_function(text);
        div_log.value += text;
    };
} (console.log.bind(console), document.getElementById("error-log")));
```

Comment: I got it working by using `div_log.textContent += text;`

Comment: Adding `console.error = console.log = (function...` made mine work for errors. This could work for other `console.[whatever]` as well.
Also @srgsanky's change was required for it to work on mine.

Comment: Yeah textContent definitely looks like it is the right attribute to use today.

Justin - when you override a browser API, usually you want to store a reference to and call the API, so your new function that you assign should still be calling the old `console.error` or `console.log` function. I don't think that can be done if you set multiple attrs with one function - will need multiple functions.

Comment: this works! but by using div_log.innerHTML += text + '<br />'; will be more clear

Comment: what do you mean old console . I don't get multiple console in single function .
your code same as pinned answer .
`if (typeof console !== 'undefined') {
      if (typeof console.log !== 'undefined') {
        console.log = (function (old_function) {
          return function (text) {
            old_function(text);
            const newMessage = text.replace('%c', '');
            setMessage([...message, newMessage]);
          };
        })(console.log.bind(console));
      }`

Answer (score 18):

None of the answers here consider console messages that get passed multiple parameters. E.g. `console.log("Error:", "error details")`).

The function that replaces the default log function better regards all function arguments (e.g. by using the `arguments` object). Here is an example:

```
console.log = function() {
  log.textContent += Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments).join(' ');
}
```

(The `Array.prototype.slice.call(...)` simply converts the `arguments` object to an array, so it can be concatenated easily with `join()`.)

When the original log should be kept working as well:

```
console.log = (function (old_log, log) { 
    return function () {
        log.textContent += Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments).join(' ');
        old_log.apply(console, arguments);
    };
} (console.log.bind(console), document.querySelector('#log')));
```

A complete solution:

```
var log = document.querySelector('#log');
['log','debug','info','warn','error'].forEach(function (verb) {
    console[verb] = (function (method, verb, log) {
        return function () {
            method.apply(console, arguments);
            var msg = document.createElement('div');
            msg.classList.add(verb);
            msg.textContent = verb + ': ' + Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments).join(' ');
            log.appendChild(msg);
        };
    })(console[verb], verb, log);
});
```

(An example of a framework that emits messages with multiple parameters is Video.js. But there is certainly many others.)

**Edit:** Another use of multiple parameters is the formatting capabilities of the console (e.g. `console.log("Status code: %d", code)`.

### About errors that are not shown

(Update Dec. 2021)

If any code crashes with an uncaught error, in might not show up in the div. One solution could be, if possible, to wrap all code in a `try` block to catch such errors and log them manually to the div.

```
try {
    // Code that might throw errors...
} catch(err) {
    // Pass the error to the overridden error log handler
    console.error(err);
}
```

Comment: +1. This is a more thoughtful answer than most. But it would be even better if you could somehow output `JSON.stringify()` result for each of the `arguments`, since often they will be objects. Currently it's just outputting `[object Object]`, and I haven't yet figured out where to use `JSON.stringify()` in your code. Thanks for the start, though.

Comment: It also took me a while to realize that I needed to place your code within `$(document).ready(function () { ... });`

Comment: Ahhh I think `msg.textContent = verb + ' ' + JSON.stringify(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments));` works.

Comment: This is the closest to what I'm looking for. Though I still can't get errors like Uncaught ReferenceError, GET errors or any other that appear on console. Is there any way we can return ANY error, live?

Comment: How can I get multiple console. I have function that log 3 console.log . and my code only show the last console . how to show all ?

Answer (score 11):

Else, if you were concerned at keeping `log`, `warn` and `error` separate from one another, you could do something like this (adapted from MST's answer):

```
var log = document.querySelector('#log');

['log','warn','error'].forEach(function (verb) {
    console[verb] = (function (method, verb, log) {
        return function (text) {
            method(text);
            // handle distinguishing between methods any way you'd like
            var msg = document.createElement('code');
            msg.classList.add(verb);
            msg.textContent = verb + ': ' + text;
            log.appendChild(msg);
        };
    })(console[verb].bind(console), verb, log);
});
```

where `#log` is your HTML element.  The variable `verb` is one of `'log'`, `'warn'`, or `'error'`.  You can then use CSS to style the text in a distinguishable way.  Note that a lot of this code isn't compatible with old versions of IE.

Comment: Checked. Best console solution in this topic.

Comment: This didn't capture any of the errors that were still sent to the Chrome Dev Tools output.

Comment: Perfect Answer. I tested in Codepen

Answer (score 7):

How about something as simple as:

```
console.log = function(message) {$('#debugDiv').append('<p>' + message + '</p>');};
console.error = console.debug = console.info =  console.log
```

Comment: I voted your answer up. This is really smart. But it caused actual console stop working

Comment: @DannyBeckett just editing with document.getElementById would be more constructive than trolling -1s on answers from 2011.

Comment: this may send console message hardcoded in the JS, but it won't send the browser's own errors.

Comment: @johnywhy - How do we access the browser's own errors?

Comment: @AndrewPaul I wish i knew.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="logger" class="web_console"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        // Overriding console object
        var console = {};

        // Getting div to insert logs
        var logger = document.getElementById("logger");

        // Adding log method from our console object
        console.log = function(text)
        {
            var element = document.createElement("div");
            var txt = document.createTextNode(text);

            element.appendChild(txt);
            logger.appendChild(element);
        }

        // testing
        console.log("Hello World...");
        console.log("WOW");

        /**
            console.log prints the message in the page instead browser console, useful to programming and debugging JS using a Android phone

        */
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a zero-dependency `npm` [module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/console-events) for this case: `console-events` (surely if you're okay to use nodejs :P)

You can add event listener like that:

```
const { console } = require('console-events');

console.addEventListener('log', (e) => {
   e.preventDefault(); //if you need to prevent normal behaviour e.g. output to devtools console
   $('#debugDiv').append('<p>' + message + '</p>');
})
```

Comment: can you please add code snippet. how to add require in browser script?

Comment: as well as it's an npm module, you can use `webpack` or `gulp` to bundle it to your javascript, so `require` will automatically put a module code into your output JS

Answer (score 0):

about console.log

### ✔️ variable number of arguments

```js
console_log = console.log

console.log = (...a)=> {
  outDiv.innerHTML += a.join(' ') + '<br>'
}
```

### ❌ handle object representation

I thinks this is complex

`JSON.stringify()` can't handle all object.

### ❌ handle other behavior

'%s' '%c' things..

not impossible,
but cumbersome

---

### some related project

- https://jsconsole.com/
  https://github.com/remy/jsconsole/blob/9bad5db/src/core/components/Console.js
- https://console.re/
  https://github.com/kurdin/console-remote
- https://npmjs.com/package/weinre
  [https://people.apache.org/~pmuellr/weinre/docs/latest/Home.html](https://people.apache.org/%7Epmuellr/weinre/docs/latest/Home.html)
- https://github.com/Tencent/vConsole
- https://eruda.liriliri.io/
  https://github.com/liriliri/eruda