# Show browser errors from console to div

Tags: javascript, html, error-handling, console

Is there a way to show all errors the console logs to a browser? For example chrome browser console, logs a cross origin error whern trying to fetch local files. Or when forming an httprequest with ar reference link that does not exit it logs an a net error automatically. Can someone view this logs into a div.?

I am aware of other posts that explain how to view errors from javascript files. I need to view browser based errors. I would prefer an answer with javascript but any is ok.

Comment: Check the answers here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6604192/showing-console-errors-and-alerts-in-a-div-inside-the-page

Comment: It is not working for browser errors or warnings. Tested on chrome and firefox. It will log thought my `console.log` statements. (e.g error : net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED)