# How to display the content of the console into a div?

Tags: javascript, console

I suppose this has been asked elsewhere but I cannot find it. Basically I want to copy all the content from the console into a div for easier debugging.

I find this question [Javascript: console.log to html](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20256760/3416774) but it's not what I want.

Comment: If u mean that u want all the console content that was written there before and you want somehow to take it and place is into a div... then it is impossible. Not all the browsers have consoles. Imagine the mobile browsers or linux text based browsers....

Comment: If that linked answer isn't what you want, then what is it that you _do_ want exactly? As that answer details and the comment above says, there's no way to get the console content without logging and storing it elsewhere to be later retrieved

Comment: Are you perhaps looking for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6604192/showing-console-errors-and-alerts-in-a-div-inside-the-page)?