# Custom console.log that keeps line number

Tags: javascript

I am trying to add some prefix to log output, but it doesn't play well in Chrome:

```
function getlog(p) {  
  return function() { 
  var mainArguments = [p].concat.call(arguments);
  console.log.bind(console).apply(console, mainArguments); }
}
```

The simplest solution works great: console.log.bind(console) , but I want to add additional text.

Related topics:

[console.log wrapper that keeps line numbers and supports most methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11308239/console-log-wrapper-that-keeps-line-numbers-and-supports-most-methods)

Comment: Why not `console.log.apply(console, mainArguments)` ?

Comment: Then I get line number of .apply method and not of the caller.

Answer (score 0):

Using `Array.prototype.concat()` on a non-array (even an array-like-object), can cause it to add the object itself to the resulting array instead of its contents. Your code was also not actually using `[p]` in the `concat()` call other than simply using it to indirectly access `Array.prototype.concat()`.

Try this:

```
function getlog(p) {  
    return function() { 
        var mainArguments = [p].concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments));
        console.log.apply(console, mainArguments); 
    };
}
```