# Console.log dev condition with line number in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, console

I use console.log for debugging on my web app, 
I have a flag variable:

var is_dev = true;

I want the console.log only runs when is_dev == true;

this is the code I used:

```
 jQuery.extend({
  log : function() {
    if (is_dev) {
      if (console) {
        console.log.apply(console, arguments);
      }
    }
  }
});
```

now I use $log('some text', someValue);

and it's working fine, the problem is that it always shows the console line number of the $log function.
I want to show also the line number of the logged text where it happened..

I don't want to go to each line and check for is_dev there, non practical and I have hundreds of them there.

Any ideas? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the answers from here [How to get JavaScript caller function line number? How to get JavaScript caller source URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1340872/how-to-get-javascript-caller-function-line-number-how-to-get-javascript-caller)

The answer from Nathan Landis is what you're looking for.