# How to find out the javascript source file name if we know the function name

Tags: javascript, jsp

I have been trying to find out a java script function source file name.

We need to figure out what java script is being executed when click a button. There is no embedded javascript in the jsp file.

I inspected that button element using firebug, we are calling a doSomething() function when we click this button.

Can anyone help me on how to find out the source file name of that doSomething() function?.

Comment: I dont think so. May be you need to parse the scripts as string and check the occurance of the function! May be not sure though

Comment: Are you using any IDE?

Comment: Yes Aniket, I am using Eclipse kepler IDE

Comment: @Prathap did you find an answer to this?

Answer (score 1):

The closest thing I could find was this thread on SO, User 'pasx' was able to do get FileName and LineNumber on IE but not on Chrome/FF. Maybe this would help: 
[How to get JavaScript caller function line number? How to get JavaScript caller source URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1340872/how-to-get-javascript-caller-function-line-number-how-to-get-javascript-caller)