# How can I get the current script name in PhantomJS?

Tags: javascript, webkit, automated-tests, phantomjs

What is the equivalent of __filename variableof nodejs in Phantomjs? I would like to get the name of the currently executing script.

Comment: Does this help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1340872/how-to-get-javascript-caller-function-line-number-how-to-get-javascript-caller ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the current script name with `phantom.scriptName` or with `system.args[0]`.

as said [here](http://phantomjs.org/api/phantom/property/scriptname.html)