# Getting Chrome's console.log to display the line that called a function

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

Is there any way in the Chrome Console tab to display the address that called a function?

I have a function that's being called but I don't know where from. I know I could break and look at the Call Stack but I'd rather just display at each entry who called it:

```
functon select_el() {
console.log("select_el called by " + ?????);

    etc.
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Are you looking for the line number or a stack trace?

Comment: I just want the number of the line where the function was called.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get JavaScript caller function line number? How to get JavaScript caller source URL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1340872/how-to-get-javascript-caller-function-line-number-how-to-get-javascript-caller)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can do that with `console.log()`. Try with `console.error()` if you're fine with red output.

Comment: Red is ok, but what would I put in console.error(???) to display the caller's line number?

Comment: `console.error()` will print a call stack with source file and line number. Check the console and you should see it (at least in Chrome).

Comment: Such a simple hack!

Answer (score 0):

The answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3806596/442351) might be what you are looking for.

It uses the trick of throwing an exception, then accessing the `LineNumber` property and printing it.