# Custom console.log function that tells you the line that it was invoked

Tags: javascript, console

Here's a simple console.log function that outputs stuff to the console:

```
function u(x) { console.log(x); } // line 41
```

But this is not altogether efficient for debugging purposes, as the browser will always output the line that console.log() was invoked on, which is line 41 in this case.

The error or whatever could be on line 741, but it would not matter. I realize that I could simply use console.log all the time instead of creating a shorter custom function, but if I don't have to, well...

How could u(x) display the actual line that it was invoked on?

Cheers!

Comment: Do you definitely want to do with WITHOUT sending the line number to the function or are you happy to send the line number?

Comment: xbrowser solution here https://github.com/stacktracejs/stacktrace.js

Comment: well, I could certainly use the option of sending the line number...Thanks for the links!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very simple to send the line number to the function. I'm not sure it's so simple to trace without a larger solution.

```
function u(x, l){
    console.log(x + ' on line ' + l);
}

u('test', new Error().lineNumber)
```

EDIT:
However, I've learned this only works in FF and Opera. There is a cross-browser solution here https://github.com/stacktracejs/stacktrace.js

Answer (score 1):

You are asking a difficult question because I have to get in to handling exceptions and what is the correct way to do that. Typically in languages like Java, you pass around exceptions instead of error messages. You could do something like

```
u(new Error("this is my error"))
```

in `function(e)` you could do `console.log(e)` where that prints the correct stack of the current execution.

Look at [How to get JavaScript caller function line number? How to get JavaScript caller source URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1340872/how-to-get-javascript-caller-function-line-number-how-to-get-javascript-caller) on how to get the actual line number.

Hope this helps.

Comment: "in function(e)".. what function(e)?

Comment: `function u(exception) {...}`. It is much cleaner to pass around the error than passing the message and line number.

Answer (score 0):

In at least chrome you can call `console.trace()` to log a stack trace to the console.

Edit:

```
function u(x) {
    console.log(x);
    console.trace();
}
```

Should give you what you want.

Comment: I assumed he would realize to put it into his custom function, but I can edit it in.

Comment: Nice! Looks like I'll have to go cross-browser for full support, although it's really irrelevant to the user, just use chrome or firefox for development lol.

Comment: Firefox supports console.trace() too (at least my edition of it).