# how to know the line where the mistake is?

Tags: javascript, line-numbers

In php when we do some thing wrong then an error is shown with the line number where it has been committed. i want this same in javascript you will understand from my codes:

```
var varlist = {};
var private = {
 str : function(nameArg, valueArg, security){
     if (varlist.hasOwnProperty(nameArg) === true){
         throw  "Variable Existance : variable "+nameArg +" is already exist in your variable list and cannot be overwritten in private type";
     }else if(security === "h"){
         var stre = String(valueArg);
         var strnew = stre.replace(/\d/g, "");
     varlist[nameArg] = strnew;
     }else if(security === "l"){
         varlist[nameArg] = String(valueArg);
     }else if(security !== "h" || security !== "n"){
             varlist[nameArg] = String(valueArg);
         throw "Unexpected Security Level: Entered " +security+" is unexpected and the default security level is low(l)";
     }
     }
    }
```

now look at the last `throw` statement if the security is not `"h"` or `"l"` then it throws an exception as you can see. 
Now suppose i am in my code editor on line says 90 and there i write `private.str("abc",9000,"o");` where `"o"` is not valid. so javascript should find that line where  `private.str("abc",9000,"o");` is written and then throw `"Unexpected Security Level: Entered " +security+" is unexpected on line "+line_number+" and the default security level is low(l)";` and here for example `line_number` is 90.
so javascript should throw this statement`"Unexpected Security Level: Entered o is unexpected on line 90 and the default security level is low(l)";`

I tried to search for this but none could help at my extent on knowledge

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use firebug or js console, or  do it in code like this

```
var
line=(new Error).stack.split("\n")[4],
nr=line.slice(line.indexOf("at ")+2, line.length);
```

([How to get JavaScript caller function line number? How to get JavaScript caller source URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1340872/how-to-get-javascript-caller-function-line-number-how-to-get-javascript-caller))

Comment: should be line.indexOf

Answer (score 0):

Javascript throws up errors by default too , but instead of printing it on the screen they are shown in the console. press F12 to open up the debug/developer mode of your browser and refresh your page. If any javascript error pops up , it will show you where it goes wrong.

using console.log you can also add your own "errors"  to the console to track.

Comment: ok but the main thing is that i want to know where is the mistake has been committed while scripting

Answer (score 0):

You can get the stack trace anywhere in your code using [this technique](http://www.eriwen.com/javascript/js-stack-trace/). This code throws and catches a fake exception and returns the content of the [Error.prototype.stack](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error/Stack). Browser support: Chrome, Firefox, IE (10 and above), Opera, Safari (6 and above).