# Is it possible to know which line of a javascript file calls one function

Tags: javascript

can this below be implemented by js?

```
 var func = function(something){
   console.log('I know it is line **4** call me'); 
 }
 func(something)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get JavaScript caller function line number? How to get JavaScript caller source URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1340872/how-to-get-javascript-caller-function-line-number-how-to-get-javascript-caller)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you find out the caller function in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/280389/how-do-you-find-out-the-caller-function-in-javascript)