# Access call stack in iframe

Tags: javascript, html

Since the chrome dev tools is blocked on my school computer (a chromebook), I have to build my own dev tools for debugging.

I chose to use a html file for debugging. This is what I have now: a giant textarea for source code, a console for debugging, and an iframe for displaying my result.

I want to view the call stack whenever `log()` is called in the iframe. Here's the code I have for logging (as a replacement for `console.log`):

```
outputIframe.contentWindow.log = function(tobelogged) {
    consoleDisplay((new Error).stack);   //for getting the stack trace https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1340872/how-to-get-javascript-caller-function-line-number-how-to-get-javascript-caller
    consoleDisplay(tobelogged);
}
```

However, this is the result:

Source code input: `<html><body><script>function abc(){log(123);};abc()</script></body></html>`

Console output:

```
<  Error
       at outputIframe.contentWindow.log (<anonymous>:244:34)
       at refresh (<anonymous>:260:47)
       at HTMLIFrameElement.outputIframe.onmouseenter (<anonymous>:235:25)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
<  123
```

This is what I want:

```
<  Error
       at abc (<anonymous>:1:16)
       at <anonymous>:1:27
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
<  123
```

or:

```
<  123
       at log (somewhere:1:16)   //this line actually does not matter
       at abc (<anonymous>:1:16)
       at <anonymous>:1:27
```

In short, I want to access the call stack inside an iframe. Any ideas?

Thank you in advance.

P.S. Since my computer is a chromebook, I don't need browser compatibility. The browser I'm using is always the latest version of google chrome.

Comment: When you say blocked, are you saying they aren’t available in chrome on chrome books or the school is intentionally blocking that capability?

Comment: https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/2657289 Look for developer tools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put `(new Error).stack` in the iframe instead of my editor source code and it solved my problem.

To prevent `beforeunload` popup and `TypeError: Assignment to constant variable.`, the way I update iframe is completely remove it and then put a clone of it back in (maybe I should just use `location.reload()` and change the `addEventListener()`).

So, I just added a line of script in the iframe and remove it before I put the actual stuff in.

```
outputIframe.contentWindow.document.write('<script>window.log = function(a){parent.consoleDisplay((new Error).stack);parent.consoleDisplay(a);}<\/script>');
outputIframe.contentWindow.document.close();     //log function will be saved and
outputIframe.contentWindow.document.write('');   //event listeners will not be saved
outputIframe.contentWindow.addEventListener("error", (event)=>{consoleDisplay(event.error.stack);});
outputIframe.contentWindow.document.write(things_to_put_in);
outputIframe.contentWindow.document.close();
```

I think another way is to create a script element, append it, and then remove it. I haven't tested it though.

Answer (score -1):

This doesn't answer your direct question, but why not just use firebug lite?  You get the functionality you are describing, plus way more:

```js
function test() {
    console.log((new Error).stack);
}

test();
```

```html
<script id="FirebugLite" src="https://getfirebug.com/firebug-lite.js#startOpened" firebuglite="4"></script>

<div id="firebug">Just use firebug lite</div>
```

Comment: Not a good answer. Basic dev tools should be available. Besides firebug stopped development a while back because their mission succeeded.

Comment: Yes, they should be, but they're not.  On a Chromebook, Chrome Developer Tools is enabled/disabled through Chrome Policies, which is maintained by the Chrome Management Console as part of a Google Work account.  The only ones with access to these policies would be his school.  You not understanding the problem doesn't make this not a good answer.

Comment: My school use goguardian, a chrome extension, to block our sites. If everyone in our school can use inspect, we can just type `window.close()` in that extension to complete disable that system. Even though it is easy to bypass goguardian, I don't think I can bypass google's police since they have a good bug report system. Methods to bypass that usually lasts for only a month.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I should just use other's code and it's more convenient. I actually figured out a way to answer my direct question for future reference.