# Log full exception on the client side from Google Apps Script back end

Tags: google-apps-script, error-handling, stackdriver, google-apps-script-addon

I am trying to debug an add on which has been published, however the exception I get back from the GAS back end does not give me much information other than the line and function it was thrown from.

Is there a way to get a more detailed error description passed back to the client?

In my example I am calling the function testException, all it currently does is throw an exception.

**CLIENT SIDE CODE**

```
google.script.run
    .withSuccessHandler(result => console.log(result))
    .withFailureHandler(error => console.error(error))
    .testException();
```

**SERVER SIDE CODE**

```
function testException() {
    throw new Error('Test message to show on client side');
}
```

All the information I get back is the following:

> at testException (code:196) (Test Add On)
>   42bb9613-6241-4ab9-b39f-01fe5c56b060

If possible I would like to get the same level of detail as the stackdriver logging. Or even just the error message 'Test message to show on client side'.

Comment: Have you tried `console.error(error.message)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get JavaScript caller function line number? How to get JavaScript caller source URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1340872/how-to-get-javascript-caller-function-line-number-how-to-get-javascript-caller)

Comment: error.message worked... I thought this would have been shown as part of the error object so didn't think to try it, thanks very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the `message` inside the [js error object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error) using:

```
console.error(error.message)
```

Comment: To add some details, there is also : `error.stack` providing filesource, function and line